# Add a column of one hot encoded data to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df == location points of multiple users data

```
    tslot             user location point  
0   2015-12-04 13:00:00 0   4356           
1   2015-12-04 13:15:00 0   4356           
2   2015-12-04 13:30:00 0   4356          
3   2015-12-04 13:45:00 0   4356          
4   2015-12-04 14:00:00 0   4356         
5   2015-12-04 14:15:00 0   4356         
6   2015-12-04 14:30:00 0   4356          
7   2015-12-04 14:45:00 0   4356          
8   2015-12-04 15:00:00 0   7645
```

I need to create a column of encoded data.

```
data = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(encoding(df))], axis=1)  #encoding is onehotencoding
```

give me multiple columns

```
         tslot           user   loaction_point  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   ... 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935
0   2015-12-04 13:00:00     0   4356            0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

but i need

```
    tslot             user location point  endoded
0   2015-12-04 13:00:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
1   2015-12-04 13:15:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
2   2015-12-04 13:30:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
3   2015-12-04 13:45:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
4   2015-12-04 14:00:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
5   2015-12-04 14:15:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
6   2015-12-04 14:30:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
7   2015-12-04 14:45:00 0   4356           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
8   2015-12-04 15:00:00 0   7645           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you need:

```
df['encoded'] = encoding(df).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
df['encoded'] = df.applymap(lambda x: np.array(pd.DataFrame(encoding(x))))
```